# How can I read an X Property using python-xlib?

Tags: python, linux, xlib

I cannot find something like XGetWindowProperty in Python Xlib...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is right there in the documentation:

http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/python-xlib_21.html#SEC20

> Method: Window get_property ( property, type, offset, length, delete =
>   0 ) Returns None or Card32('property_type'), Card8('format'),
>   PropertyData('value'), Card32('bytes_after'),

Comment: The meaning of the parameters, however, is not right there in the documentation. Nor is it here, in this answer, which is the first result on google.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using `get_property`, use `get_full_property`. It hides the stranger aspects of `XGetWindowProperty`'s API.

I had to grep through the python-xlib source to find examples of its use, but here's a simplified version of what I ended up writing to make use of it.

This definition of `_NET_CLIENT_LIST` from [this spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html):

```
_NET_CLIENT_LIST, WINDOW[]/32
```

...and this definition of `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL` from [this spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html):

```
_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL, left, right, top, bottom, left_start_y, left_end_y,
right_start_y, right_end_y, top_start_x, top_end_x, bottom_start_x,
bottom_end_x,CARDINAL[12]/32
```

...translate into this Python code:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import Xatom

display = Display()
root = display.screen(0)['root']

StrutPartial = namedtuple('StrutPartial', 'left right top bottom'
    ' left_start_y left_end_y right_start_y right_end_y'
    ' top_start_x, top_end_x, bottom_start_x bottom_end_x')


def query_property(win, name, prop_type, format_size, empty=None):
    if isinstance(win, int):
        # Create a Window object for the Window ID
        win = display.create_resource_object('window', win)
    if isinstance(name, str):
        # Create/retrieve the X11 Atom for the property name
        name = display.get_atom(name)

    result = win.get_full_property(name, prop_type)
    if result and result.format == format_size:
        return result.value
    return empty

window_ids = ([root.id] +
    list(query_property(root, '_NET_CLIENT_LIST', Xatom.WINDOW, 32, [])))

for wid in window_ids:
    result = query_property(wid, '_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL', Xatom.CARDINAL, 32)

    if result:
        # Toss it in a namedtuple to avoid needing opaque numeric indexes
        strut = StrutPartial(*result)
        print(strut)
```

...which prints this example output:

```
StrutPartial(left=0, right=0, top=0, bottom=30, left_start_y=0, left_end_y=0, right_start_y=0, right_end_y=0, top_start_x=0, top_end_x=0, bottom_start_x=3200, bottom_end_x=4479)
StrutPartial(left=0, right=0, top=0, bottom=30, left_start_y=0, left_end_y=0, right_start_y=0, right_end_y=0, top_start_x=0, top_end_x=0, bottom_start_x=1280, bottom_end_x=3199)
StrutPartial(left=0, right=0, top=0, bottom=0, left_start_y=0, left_end_y=0, right_start_y=0, right_end_y=0, top_start_x=0, top_end_x=0, bottom_start_x=0, bottom_end_x=0)
StrutPartial(left=0, right=0, top=0, bottom=30, left_start_y=0, left_end_y=0, right_start_y=0, right_end_y=0, top_start_x=0, top_end_x=0, bottom_start_x=0, bottom_end_x=1279)
```

(`result.value` is an `array.array` of twelve 32-bit integers, because the spec calls for `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL` to be set to a `CARDINAL[12]/32`. You can iterate or index `array.array` the same way you would a normal `list` or `tuple`, but a `namedtuple` is a simple, comfy way to use named properties instead.)

Comment: ...since I ran into the same "Why is this the top result on Google?" problem and wanted to give something back after solving my problem.